# Erro ao tentar logar com a foto de perfil atualizada

Tags: php, laravel, imagem

Fiz um sistema de troca de foto do usuário, quando eu troco a foto, deslogo e tento logar de novo, ele me volta com esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

essa é minha linha 11:

```html
 <img src="images/uploads/avatars/{{ $user->avatar }}" alt="" class="circle responsive-img">
```

Esse é meu controller:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use Image;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function profile(){
        return view('partials.alunoform', array('user'=> Auth::user()) );
        
    }

 public function aluno(){
        return view('partials.aluno', array('user'=> Auth::user()) );
        
    }

    public function update_avatar(Request $request){

     // Handle the user upload of avatar
     if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
      $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
      $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
      Image::make($avatar->getRealPath())->resize(450, 450)->save( public_path('images/uploads/avatars/' . $filename ) );

      $user = Auth::user();
      $user->avatar = $filename;
      $user->save();
     }

     return view('partials.alunoform', array('user'=> Auth::user()) );

    }
}
```

Eu li em lugar que é preciso fazer um check para ver se o usuário está logado, como posso fazer esse "check"? Se não for isso, como posso resolver esse erro?